# Nested IF formula with VLOOKUP

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, excel-2007, vlookup

In cell D5:

```
=IF(VLOOKUP(C5,'store1'!$F$4:$F$29,1)=C5,"store1","")&(IF(VLOOKUP(C5,'store2'!$F$4:$F$29,1)=C5,"\store2","")&(IF(VLOOKUP(C5,'store3'!$F$4:$F$29,1)=C5,"\store3","")&(IF(VLOOKUP(C5,'store4'!$F$4:$F$29,1)=C5,"\store4","")&(IF(VLOOKUP(C5,'store5'!$F$4:$F$29,1)=C5,"\store5","")&(IF(VLOOKUP(C5,'store6'!$F$4:$F$29,1)=C5,"\store6","")&(IF(VLOOKUP(C5,'store7'!$F$4:$F$29,1)=C5,"\store7","")&(IF(VLOOKUP(C5,'store8'!$F$4:$F$29,1)=C5,"\store8","")&(IF(VLOOKUP(C5,'store9'!$F$4:$F$29,1)=C5,"\store9","")&(IF(VLOOKUP(C5,'store10'!$F$4:$F$29,1)=C5,"\store10",""))))))))))
```

I have ten store sheets with working employees name and one "all store employees name" sheet. Sometimes a few employees work in two stores and swipe with store1 to store2 or store3 or other.

What I want is if some employee worked in more then one store then store (ie sheet name) number show in 'all store employees name' sheet.

Example: "all store employees name" c5 to c30 is A to Z alphabet
and f4 to f29 A to Z alphabet in all store.

The formula works but not properly, A to M show `#N/A`.

Comment: Why do all the stores except *store1* have a backslash as a prefix? Should they all have it? Should none of them have it? Is it correct as it is?

Comment: @pnuts - But if the employee only worked in store2 and store3 the results would *start* with a backslash; e.g. \store2\store3. The results are inconsistent. It would be better practise to separate with a space and [TRIM](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TRIM-function-410388FA-C5DF-49C6-B16C-9E5630B479F9) the result(s).

Comment: @pnuts - An [IF](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/if-function-a918d97a-251e-4af5-bd15-09b12b8742bb)([ISTEXT](https://support.office.com/fi-fi/article/ISTEXT-function-e0dbe551-2464-4b41-b906-98cd970821f4)(... could take care of the errors; I'm thinking about the results.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87715/discussion-between-jeeped-and-pnuts).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the employee is not found in any store, that will be an error for that store. The most efficient method of looking for a value to simply exist is the [MATCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) (even more efficient than [COUNTIF](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/COUNTIF-function-E0DE10C6-F885-4E71-ABB4-1F464816DF34)) but you need to check if MATCH is returning a row number when found or an `#N/A` error where no match was found. The [ISNUMBER function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/is-functions-490afee4-fd91-4839-89d4-1257a21b4e25) can determine that.

```
=MID(IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(C5, store1!$F$4:$F$29, 0)), "\store1", "")
    &IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(C5, store2!$F$4:$F$29, 0)), "\store2", "")
    &IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(C5, store3!$F$4:$F$29, 0)), "\store3", "")
    &IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(C5, store4!$F$4:$F$29, 0)), "\store4", "")
    &IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(C5, store5!$F$4:$F$29, 0)), "\store5", "")
    &IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(C5, store6!$F$4:$F$29, 0)), "\store6", "")
    &IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(C5, store7!$F$4:$F$29, 0)), "\store7", "")
    &IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(C5, store8!$F$4:$F$29, 0)), "\store8", "")
    &IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(C5, store9!$F$4:$F$29, 0)), "\store9", "")
    &IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(C5, store10!$F$4:$F$29, 0)), "\store10", ""), 2, 99)
```

I've added the backslash to all store values and trimmed off the first backslash from the result no matter which store supplied it.

You can keep the 'whitespace' (e.g. linefeeds and spaces) in the formula to help you make more sense of it once it is in the worksheet's formula bar. This formula may *look* complicated but it actually does much less work than even the most rudimentary array formula.

Comment: Perfect Jeeped, this is exactly what i want thank you so much,